# Where can i find a good in depth guide to C# 3?

Tags: c#, documentation, c#-3.0

It seems that C# 3 hit me without me even noticing, could you guys tell me about good in depth guides to C# 3? from lambda to linq to everything else that was introduced with the third version of the language.

Printed books would be nice, but online guides would be even better!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[ScottGu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/default.aspx) has some great posts on C# 3:

- [The C# ?? null coalescing operator (and using it with LINQ)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/09/20/the-new-c-null-coalescing-operator-and-using-it-with-linq.aspx)
- [LINQ to SQL: Part 8](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/27/linq-to-sql-part-8-executing-custom-sql-expressions.aspx) (this is an 8 part series, check the top of the post for links to the first 7)
- [Automatic Properties, Object Initializers, and Collection Initializers](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/03/08/new-c-orcas-language-features-automatic-properties-object-initializers-and-collection-initializers.aspx)
- [Extension Methods](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/03/13/new-orcas-language-feature-extension-methods.aspx)
- [Lambda Expressions](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/08/new-orcas-language-feature-lambda-expressions.aspx)
- [Query Syntax](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/21/new-orcas-language-feature-query-syntax.aspx)
- [Anonymous Types](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/15/new-orcas-language-feature-anonymous-types.aspx?CommentPosted=true)

Some more useful links:

- [MSDN: Overview of C# 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308966.aspx)
- [David Hayden: C# 3.0 Tutorials and Examples](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/11/30/CSharpTutorialsAndExamples.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

There are some high quality blogs out there.

some of my favorites: [Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/tags/Lambda+Expressions/default.aspx), [Eric White](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericwhite/pages/FP-Tutorial.aspx), [Scott Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/tags/LINQ/default.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

I've been told this is a good book [C# in Depth](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988363).

MS Training kits [Visual Studio 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5 Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?familyid=8BDAA836-0BBA-4393-94DB-6C3C4A0C98A1&displaylang=en) and [.NET Framework 3.5 Enhancements Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=355c80e9-fde0-4812-98b5-8a03f5874e96&displaylang=en)

Channel 9 [presentation\videos](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/DavidAiken/VS2008-Training-Kit-Whats-new-in-C-30/)

Answer (score 3):

I've read the first 4 chapters from 'C# In Depth' by Jon Skeet so far and would recommend this book.

Answer (score 2):

Just another recommendation for C# in Depth; not only will it fully explain C# 3.0 - but it will also significantly improve your understanding of C# 2.0 - for example, a lot of the more subtle nuances of iterator blocks or captured variables.

Definitely worth a read.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308966.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If your looking for some dead tree reference, I recommend Pro C# 2008 and the .NET 3.5 Platform by Andrew Troelsen.

http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/reader/1590598849/ref=sib_rdr_toc?ie=UTF8&p=S006&j=0#reader-page

Answer (score 1):

I've found [C# 3.0 in a Nutshell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596527578) to be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I found [Pro LINQ: Language Integrated Query in C# 2008](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590597893) to be very helpful for this.  It has a chapter which covers all the new language features in 3, and of course the rest of the book goes into a deep dive on LINQ.  I would highly recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

[The C# 3 specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/8/8/388e7205-bc10-4226-b2a8-75351c669b09/CSharp%20Language%20Specification.doc) gives a complete description of the language, however this might be *too* much detail for your needs.